# Styles loaded in order, but Bootstrap still overrides WordPress child

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I created a WordPress child theme which renders Bootstrap and child-styles.css correctly in the source code:

[Source code stylesheet order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ddAZ.jpg)

Yet the color of my link is being overridden by Bootstrap still, as seen by inspecting with Chrome:

[Chrome inspection window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZEcH.jpg)

I don't have any .scss files in my Bootstrap directory, although I admit I'm not sure how the files compile to CSS. Either way, with the child-styles.css loading after Bootstrap, how is it still being overridden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> with the child-styles.css loading after Bootstrap, how is it still being overridden?

The reason that happens is because the Bootstrap rule has a higher **specificity**. So, it wins.

This: `.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link` is much more specific than this: `.nav-link`.

If you give your custom rule the same level of specificity or higher, your custom rule will win and override.

Comment: Brilliant! I simply did wrote `.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color:aquamarine;
}` and it worked, assuming although I used the same specificity, the child-styles.css loads last and thus gets used.